# Call contract function throws: Out of Gas

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I just started with my first ether contract.

I used Solidity 0.6.4, everything worked fine, but then I added the argument 'remark' to the rateCandidate function. 'rateCandidate(bytes32 candidate, uint32 score, **bytes32 remark**)' and now I always get an 'Out of Gas' error,
I tried to get more information but I´m totally stuck here... I attachted the contract too, something must be totally wrong, I run it with Ganache, 100 Eth when I deploy the contract.
Do I have to consider some specific things when using a bytes32 array in a struct? Because with uint32 it worked very well.

I hope it is well enough explained, thanks in advance.

```
(node:17779) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas
at Object.ErrorResponse (/home/user/Repositories/Dapp/chapter2/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:29:16)
at /home/user/Repositories/Dapp/chapter2/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/src/index.js:140:36
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/home/user/Repositories/Dapp/chapter2/node_modules/web3-providers-http/src/index.js:110:13)
at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/user/Repositories/Dapp/chapter2/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/home/user/Repositories/Dapp/chapter2/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:208:14)
at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/home/user/Repositories/Dapp/chapter2/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:318:14)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/user/Repositories/Dapp/chapter2/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:289:61)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:466:23)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

(node:17779) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:17779) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

```
contract RateContract {
    struct Rate {
        bool isValue;
        bytes32[] remark;
        uint32[] rates;
    }
   
  mapping (bytes32 => Rate) public ratesReceived;
 
  bytes32[] public candidateList;

  constructor(bytes32[] memory candidateNames) public {
    candidateList = candidateNames;
  }

  function totalRatesFor(bytes32 candidate) view public returns (uint32, uint32, bytes32[] memory) {
    bytes32[] memory remark = ratesReceived[candidate].remark;
    if (ratesReceived[candidate].isValue != true)
    {
        return (0, 0, remark);
    }

    uint32 count = 0;
    uint32 sum = 0;
    for (uint j = 0; j < ratesReceived[candidate].rates.length; j++) {
        count += 1;
        sum += ratesReceived[candidate].rates[j];
    }
    return (sum/count, count, remark);
  }

  function rateCandidate(bytes32 candidate, uint32 score, bytes32 comment) public {
    ratesReceived[candidate].isValue = true;
    ratesReceived[candidate].rates.push(score);
    ratesReceived[candidate].remark.push(comment);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share javascript code. looks  like js code is causing issue

Comment: I just used node/web3 to execute my contract. ```deployedContract.methods.rateCandidate(web3.utils.asciiToHex('Candidate1'),50, web3.utils.asciiToHex('comment1')).send({from: '0xce4a79aaFA3BF6719c7f17861d0E6Bc09eE4b258'}).then((f) => console.log(f))```